Virial theorem for liquids and solids?
It might be a stupid question, but I was wondering whether or not the virial theorem, or a generalized one, can be used for liquids or solids. I know one of the key thing is having a central force like gravity. But, could a sphere of liquid under the influence of its own gravity be considered in the context of the virial theorem? And likewise for solids? The big difference compared to gases would be the much stronger interatomic or intermolecular forces. Do they cause any issues here?
